# Refresh a Bootstrap navbar using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am currently developing a new project that uses AngularJS and Twitter Bootstrap 3.0 for styling.

The project also uses ASP.NET MVC WebAPI to provide a RESTful API with role based security as well as generating bearer and refresh tokens using Owin and OAuth.

One of the key aspects of the project is that it must be able to refresh the navbar menu by adding and/or removing menu options depending on the roles/permissions assigned to individual users.  If a user is currently logged into the application and a system administrator decides to add or removed roles for the logged in user I would like AngularJS to automatically reload the navbar, which will magically show or hide options based on the roles the user has.

I do not know very much about AngularJS at this point and would like to know if this is possible?  I have heard something called `$scope.apply()` and that it could be used for this, but as an inexperienced AngularJS user I am not sure how this could be used.

This is a portion of my view that displays the menu bar, and as you can see I am using functions to show/hide menu options.  I'd like these functions to be re-evaluated again if their values change once a new refresh token has been generated by a WebAPI call.

```
<li data-ng-if="isAuthenticated()" class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Invoice <b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a data-ng-if="isUserInInvoiceRole()" data-ui-sref="addInvoice">Add Invoice</a></li>
        <li data-ng-if="isUserInInvoiceRole()" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a data-ng-if="isUserInCreditNoteRole()" data-ui-sref="addCreditNote">Issue Credit Note</a></li>
        <li data-ng-if="isUserInCreditNoteRole()" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a data-ui-sref="showDaybook">Daybook</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a data-ui-sref="showCustomerLedger">Customer Ledger</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

At present the only way I can force the navbar to be refreshed is by doing a page refresh via F5, which proves that the role based system works, but I'd like it to work automatically by reloading the navbar.

**Controller**

```
'use strict';

appModule.controller('indexController', ['$scope', '$state', 'authService',
    function ($scope, $state, authService) {

        $scope.isAuthenticated = function () {
            return authService.isAuthenticated();
        };

        $scope.isUserInCreditNoteRole = function () {
            return authService.isAuthenticated() && authService.isUserInCreditNoteRole();
        };

        $scope.isUserInInvoiceRole = function () {
            return authService.isAuthenticated() && authService.isUserInInvoiceRole();
        };

        $scope.isUserInOrderRole = function () {
            return authService.isAuthenticated() && authService.isUserInOrderRole();
        };

        $scope.isUserInAdminRole = function () {
            return authService.isAuthenticated() && authService.isInAdminRole();
        };

    }]);
```

**Auth service**

Here is the auth service with the relevant code.  Bear in mind that the [roles.xxx] are just constants.

```
'use strict';

appModule.factory('authService', ['$http', 'roles',
    function ($http, roles) {

        var authServiceFactory = {};

        var authentication = {
            isAuth: false,
            roles: "Anon"
        };

        var checkRoles = function (access) {
            var result = false;
            for (var a in access) {
                console.log(access[a]);
                for (var b in access[a]) {
                    if (authentication.roles.indexOf(access[a][b]) >= 0) {
                        result = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (result)
                    break;
            }
            console.log('result ' + result);
            return result;
        };

        var isUserInInvoiceRole = function () {
            return checkRoles([roles.invoice]);
        };

        var isUserInOrderRole = function () {
            return checkRoles([roles.order]);
        };

        var isUserInCreditNoteRole = function () {
            return checkRoles([roles.creditNote]);
        };

        var isInAdminRole = function () {
            return checkRoles([roles.admin]);
        };

        var isAuthenticated = function () {
        return authentication.isAuth;
    }

    authServiceFactory.isAuthenticated = isAuthenticated;
    authServiceFactory.isUserInCreditNoteRole = isUserInCreditNoteRole;
    authServiceFactory.isUserInInvoiceRole = isUserInInvoiceRole;
    authServiceFactory.isUserInOrderRole = isUserInOrderRole;
    authServiceFactory.isInAdminRole = isInAdminRole;

    return authServiceFactory;

}]);
```

Comment: You're already there. If the value of any of your `data-ng-if` functions changes (`isUserInInvoiceRole()` returns a truthy value, for example), the item will be displayed. Where do those functions live?

Comment: These functions live in the parent controller, but the view didn't get refreshed automatically when the function values become true.  I have updated my question to show the controller code.

Comment: Can you also post the `isUserInX` functions from your `authService`?

Comment: I have posted the code from the authService.

Comment: I can't see any problems yet -- have you tested your `checkRoles` function to make sure that's returning good results?

Comment: Yes I have tested the `checkRoles` function and it works perfectly.  I have used `console.log()` extensively to prove this.  If I add a new role called `CreditNote` to a logged in user to the DB and the access token expires the AngularJS application gets a HTTP 401 error and calls the `\token` endpoint to request a new access token.  The response will then bring down the new roles into the `authentication.roles` property, but the navbar doesn't show the `Credit Note` option until I press F5.

Comment: Ok. The problem could be that when the `authentication.roles` property is updated, Angular doesn't know that it _should_ recheck those `ng-if` statements. One solution is to use `$scope.broadcast` to broadcast an event message, and then use `$scope.on` in the controller to listen for it and run a refresh function. (Also, consider putting your relevant code into a JSFiddle - that makes it a lot easier for us to debug)

Comment: Ok I will try those suggestions tomorrow as I'm not at my computer at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to resolve this myself after understanding how AngularJS watches updates to a controllers' scope.

I simply repopulated the `authentication` object in the authentication service, after a new refresh token had been retrieved and the nav bar updated instantly.

Comment: It would've been a lot nicer if you had posted your code too.